# loop for txt split file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make this following query loop through and split all the text files in the current directory. I currently have two different files named `TestingInfo[1]` & `TestingInfo[2]`.

Directory where files are located: `\\C\users$\Pepe\Desktop\TestInfoFolder`

The files look like this:

`TestingInfo[1]`:

```
[IMPORT]
1
2
3
[IMPORT]
4
5
6
```

`TestingInfo[2]`:

```
[IMPORT]
7
8
9
10
```

Code I have so far:

```
$Path = "\\C\users$\Pepe\Desktop\TestInfoFolder"
$InputFile = (Join-Path $Path "TestingInfo[1].txt")
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
$N = 1

While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($Line -match "[IMPORT]") {
        $OutputFile = $matches[0] + $N + ".txt"
        $N++
    }

    Add-Content (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile) $Line
}
```

Comment: There's a few things I see here. You do not explain well what you hope to accomplish. Do you want 3 output files? What do you expect them to contain? What should they be named? Also, `"[IMPORT]"` is not a good regex match for your `-match` argument. That will match any line that contains at least one of the characters I, M, P, O, R, or T. ([see example here](https://regex101.com/r/kV3wZ7/1))

Comment: An example where `Select-String -Between 'IMPORT'` to select all the import groups in one move be neat, if it existed. Vote for it if you also think it would be neat: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/14951235-add-parameters-to-select-string-for-matching-all-l

Comment: what I was attempting to explain is that I have two files that contain the txt posted above. The first file, TestingInfo[1], has two sets of records that I need to extract into separate files and the second file test, TestingInfo[2] has one. I would like the function to separate each one of those blocks regardless of how many files are in the directory. It doesn't matter what they are named. Something like "TestingInfo[1]_N" where N would equal the number of blocks that came from the file.

Comment: For example TestingInfo[1] would have two files produced that will contain the following:  Results for File 1: [IMPORT] 1,2,3  File 2: [IMPORT] 4,5,6

Answer (score 0):

Your sort of doing it the hard way, calling the .NET libraries directly.

This approach should be about right, and much more simple / in line with PowerShell.

```
$curFileContents
$i = 0

Get-ChildItem "pathOfFiles\" | {
  Get-Content $_ | ForEach-Object {
      $line = $_.Split(" ")
      foreach ($word in $line)
      {
          if ($word -match "[INPUT]")
          {
              $i++
          }
          else
          {
              $curFileContents += $word  + " "
          }
      }
      $curFileContents | Out-File -FilePath "PathToFile\output$i.txt"
  }
}
```

Which gives text files where the content looks like:

> 1 2 3

Reusing your code, and adding in the get-child item would look like:

```
$Path = "\\C\users$\Pepe\Desktop\TestInfoFolder"
Get-ChildItem $Path | foreach-object {
   $InputFile = $_.FullName
   $Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
   $N = 1

   While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
       if ($Line -match "[IMPORT]") {
           $OutputFile = $matches[0] + $N + ".txt"
           $N++
       }

       Add-Content (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile) $Line
   }
}
```

Comment: In your code I see that it repeats the testingInfo[1] file twice. I need to spilt all chunks of data in both files into separate files. In my code I am able to do that, but I cant loop through all files in the directory and do the same.                                                                                                       So the original "TestingInfo1" file will be broken up into two separate files: Results file 1: [IMPORT] 1 2 3        Results file 2: [IMPORT] 4 5 6

Comment: Original File "TestingInfo[2]". Resulting file will be Results file 1: [IMPORT] 7 8 9 10

Comment: Ah, that's easy enough. Just wrap it all in get-childitem and replace the filename earlier with $_ or $_.FullName (edited above)

Comment: Where would I put the getchilditem in my code? I tried a bit yesterday but I kept getting an error.

Comment: **Really** spelling it out now. Take a gander at that.

Comment: For some reason the first output file contains the first block of TestingInfo[1] and 1st block of TestingInfo[2].

Comment: Would you know why the second file would be appending to the first results file? Im confused. Any help would be appreciated.